# Chrome html5 doctype changes width of input, but not select

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

In current stable Chrome (48.0.2564.97), prepending the html5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) to the following HTML changes the width of the `<input>`, but not the `<select>`.

The `<input>` overflows the `<td>` on the right side, but the `<select>` doesn't.

1. Why does that occur?
2. How can I prevent it, yet still use html5?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
.input-cell > * {
    width: 100%;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr><td class="input-cell"><input name="note" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="input-cell"><select name="formatted"><option></option></select></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "prepending doctype"? Are you adding it dynamically or something? If so, how?

Comment: I mean if I have one html file that has the doctype in the first line, compared to a different html file that is exactly the same except that the doctype isn't in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need here is box-sizing (the first 3 lines of additional CSS). If you have a look through a browser other than chrome with your old code you'd see that the same problem would be occuring. box-sizing will largely fix the problem - except for chrome. Argh! This is due to the setup of chrome default boxes. To fix this you have to define the padding, margin, height and border of your inputs (the next 4 lines of additional code).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .input-cell > * {
                width: 100%;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
                box-sizing:border-box;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr><td class="input-cell"><input name="note" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="input-cell"><select name="formatted"><option></option></select></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With that your text boxes should line up in any browser. Of course you may want to make them a little prettier than I have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm only targeting Chrome, since it's for an internal application.  `box-sizing:border-box;` by itself fixed it for me.  The last 4 properties were unnecessary.  Are they just necessary for elements other than input and select?  Or am I somehow missing something that they solve for input and select?

Comment: Sorry about that, thought you might have only been testing on chrome with plans for elsewhere. No, I'm pretty sure you'll just be fine with that if you're only using chrome. The last 4 lines are just to remove any possible irregularities between browsers.